# Recursively reproject shapefiles in folders and subfolders

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, gdal, convert, ogr2ogr

I would like to recursively reproject shapefiles with different source projections. The shapefiles (109) are saved in deep folder trees. They have 4 different CRS, all the *.prj are present.
As result, I need all shapefiles reprojected to one CRS (EPSG:32632), keeping the name and the path.

In addition it would be great, if all shapes containing in a folder would also be converted to one GPKG per folder.

Comment: which operating system?

Comment: Linux (Mint), Windows 10 (VirtualBox)

Answer (score 3):

On Linux systems it is fairly easy, provided there is an easy regex that describes the folders with the shapefiles in. [`ogr2ogr`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html#ogr2ogr) will create a new [geopackage](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gpkg.html#vector-gpkg) and add a table for each spatial file it finds in the directory and handle the reprojection at the same time.

```
for folder in **/shapefiles
do
  ogr2ogr -f GPKG -t_srs EPSG:32632 $folder/filename.gpkg $folder
done
```

Comment: looks great! But, sorry, where do I put in the code?

Comment: it's shell code so you can run it at the prompt anywhere

Comment: Okay, I thought so, but returns that error: Unable to open datasource `**/geodata' with the following drivers. (I placed the correct path)

Comment: which shell do you use? it might not recognise `**` - try the path with `ls`

Comment: I tryed with several combinations. Everytime the same: Unable to open datasource XXX with the following drivers. I used Guake Terminal and the standard terminal from Mint

Comment: and there are shapefiles in `**/geodata` - what does `ls -d **/geodata` give you?

Comment: ...just the same. Your solution seems simple and nice but I now solved the problem with the python-script from BERA

Answer (score 2):

This will reproject all shapefiles then package them into geopackages, one for each folder with shapes. For example I get the geopackages

```
/home/bera/Downloads/shape/svk/riks/riks.gpkg
/home/bera/Downloads/shape/svk/riks/subfolder/subfolder.gpkg
```

I use [collections.defaultdict list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples) to create a dictionary of `folder:[all shapes in that folder]` and then iterate over the folders and list of shapefiles

```
import os
from collections import defaultdict as dd
shapefolder = r'/home/bera/Downloads/shape/'

#List all shapefiles
mainfolders = dd(list)
for root, folder, files in os.walk(shapefolder):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.shp'):
            mainfolders[root].append(os.path.join(root, file))

#Reproject shapes
for folders, shapefiles in mainfolders.items():
    for shapefile in shapefiles:
        print(shapefile)
        processing.run("native:reprojectlayer", 
        {'INPUT':shapefile,'TARGET_CRS':QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:32632'),
        'OUTPUT':shapefile})

#Create one geopackage for each folder
for folder, shapefiles in mainfolders.items():
    for shapefile in shapefiles:
        processing.run("gdal:convertformat", 
            {'INPUT':shapefile,'OPTIONS':'-nln \"{0}\" -append'.format(os.path.basename(shapefile).split('.')[0]),
            'OUTPUT':os.path.join(folder,'{0}.gpkg'.format(os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(folder))))})
```

[image]
(
[image]
)

Comment: Working great so far! But: the resulting Shapes/GPKGs have got the tables but without the features - they are empty

Comment: ...maybe because the created shapes overwrite the existing ones? The results should get a prefix or suffix to check that out. Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar with python

Comment: Yes the projected ones overwrite the original. (You said you want to keep name and path). I will test again later, I dont have the data on this computer

Comment: I adapted the script so that the resulting shapes are not empty:

`processing.run("native:reprojectlayer", {'INPUT':shapefile, 'TARGET_CRS':'EPSG:32632', 'OUTPUT':shapefile[:-4]+"_reprojected.shp"})`

So what I did was to pass the TARGET_CRS as string only and save the intermediate shp file with a different name. Maybe you can adapt your answer accordingly BERA?